# How to get non empty attribute documents from mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get the document from mongodb which is having attribute with non empty.

```
 document1
       {
           "reviews" : { "title" : "Hello"}
       }

       document2
       {
           "reviews": {}
       }
```

Expected document

```
document1
       {
           "reviews" : { "title" : "Hello"}
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/). Simple usage.

```
db.collection.find({ "reviews.title": {$exists: true } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
{ reviews: { $exists: true } }
```

EDIT:

To also check for "empty objects":

```
{"reviews": {$exists:true, "$ne":{}}}
```

Comment: Which would actually still return the blank document.